# Segmentation fault, Pilha em c

Tags: c

Não sei o que pode estar dando esse erro em meu código, por favor se alguém souber o que está acontecendo. Aqui vai o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct no {
    int dado;
    struct no *prox;
};

typedef struct no criano;
typedef criano *no_pont;
int tam;

//void cria_Fila(no_pont *head, no_pont *tail);
int fila_Vazia(no_pont head);
void insere_Fila(no_pont *head, no_pont *tail, int valor);
int retira_Fila(no_pont *head, no_pont *tail);
void imprime_Fila(no_pont atual);

int main() {
    no_pont head=NULL;
    no_pont tail=NULL;
//  cria_Fila(&head,&tail);
    insere_Fila(&head, &tail, 52);
    insere_Fila(&head, &tail, 21);
    insere_Fila(&head, &tail, 532);
    imprime_Fila(head);

    return 0;
}

/*void cria_Fila(no_pont *head, no_pont *tail, int tam){
head=NULL;
tail=NULL;
tam=0;
}*/

int fila_Vazia(no_pont head) {
    return head=NULL;
}

void insere_Fila(no_pont *head, no_pont *tail, int valor) {
    no_pont novo;
    novo = (no_pont*)malloc(sizeof(no_pont));

    if(novo!=NULL) {
        novo->dado=valor;
        novo->prox=NULL;

        if(fila_Vazia(*head)) {
            *head=novo;
        } else {
            (*tail)->prox=novo;
        }
    } else {
        printf("%d nao inserido. Nao ha espaco na memoria\n",valor);
    }
    tam++;
}

int retira_Fila(no_pont *head, no_pont *tail) {
    int valor;
    no_pont aux;

    valor = (*head)->dado;
    aux= *head;
    *head= (*head)->prox;
    if( *head == NULL ) {
        *tail = NULL;
    }
    free(aux);
    tam--;
    return valor;
}

void imprime_Fila(no_pont atual) {
    if(atual == NULL) {
        printf("A fila esta vazia\n");
    } else {
        printf("A fila e: ");

        while(atual!=NULL) {
            printf("%c  ",atual->dado);
            atual=atual->prox;
        }

        printf("NULL\n\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem alguns erros pequenos no código:

- A comparação no `fila_Vazia` está feita só com um `=` assim:

  ```
  return head=NULL;
  ```
- Na função `insere_Fila` a alocação do novo nó não está correta:

  ```
  novo = (no_pont*)malloc(sizeof(no_pont));
  ```

  Pois aloca um ponteiro para o nó em vez de o nó em si.
- Ainda na função `insere_Fila` não está a modificar o `tail` apropriadamente
- O `printf` no `imprime_Fila` está `%c` quando o `dado` é do tipo `int`.

A função `fila_Vazia` e `insere_Fila` deveriam ficar assim:

```
int fila_Vazia(no_pont head) {
    return head==NULL; //agora com ==
}

void insere_Fila(no_pont *head, no_pont *tail, int valor) {
    no_pont novo;
    novo = (no_pont)malloc(sizeof(criano)); //alocação de criano em vez de no_pont

    if(novo!=NULL) {
        novo->dado=valor;
        novo->prox=NULL;

        if(fila_Vazia(*head)) {
            *head=novo;
        } else {
            (*tail)->prox=novo;
        }

        *tail = novo; //modificação do tail para o ultimo nó, que é o novo

    } else {
        printf("%d nao inserido. Nao ha espaco na memoria\n",valor);
    }
    tam++;
}
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/x347nI)

**Sugestão**

Uma vez que está a utilizar `tam` para o tamanho e `tail` para a cauda da lista seria boa ideia usar uma outra estrutura que representa a lista, com esses 3 campos.

Exemplo:

```
struct lista {
    no_pont head,
    no_pont tail,
    size_t tam
};
```